# Parenting with automatic weights destroys the object

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I downloaded this mouse from the blender page and now I try to parent the object to the bones with automatic weights. but the object changes completely.

This is before I parent the object to the bones.
[image]

This is after the parenting.

[image]

Here is the file to the blend. [link](https://download.blender.org/demo/eevee/mr_elephant/mr_elephant.blend)

Comment: Check and make sure that you don't have more than one armature modifier in the stack. Weirdness like this can happen when we retry skinning after a failed attempt, because each attempt creates a new armature modifier, and you only want to have one.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it didn't solve it.https://download.blender.org/demo/eevee/mr_elephant/mr_elephant.blend there is just one armature.